# Ooyala HTML5 Player

Tags: html5-video, ooyala

Maybe I'm missing something, but hopefully someone here knows better than I...

I'm trying to install [Ooyala](http://ooyala.com)'s video player using their [HTML5 API](http://www.ooyala.com/support/docs/player_api#html5). However, in their [HTML5 demo](http://demo.ooyala.com/product-demos/html5-demo.html), there's no HTML5 to be found, just a flash player (as in the rest of their examples). Do they not actually have an HTML5 API, or am I doing something wrong? I was expecting video to be dropped in via a `<video>` tag or object embed or anything other than Flash.

Answer (score 7):

Ooyala has recently upgraded to V3, also they have deprecated AS3 API. V3 supports flash video with HTML5 fallback. Also you can set HTML5 option by default as shown in example below. It's shame they haven't done HTML5 with flash fallback.

You can specify HTML5 platform as shown below. If you don't specify anything, flash version will be used by default with HTML5 fallback.

```
<script src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/MzZiMzc1ZDUzZGVlYmMxNzA3Y2MzNjBk?platform=html5'></script>
```

This demo uses HTML5 version:
http://demo.ooyala.com/product-demos/OOview_Win8/OOView/player.html

More implementation information can be found here:
http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_embedplayer.html

Answer (score 3):

The Ooyala Player will use html5 only if it detects that the user is on an iOS device.  To test on the Desktop, use Safari.  Select Develop -> User Agent -> (Any iOS Device), then open the link.

Comment: This is for V2 only- please see Gurpreet's answer for info on our current version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about this. However, I think that Ooyala did not launch HTML5 API yet. As far as I know, Brightcove just launched a Limited Availability of the HTML5 API, and I was under the impression that this was a step ahead in the HTML5 video market.